# Rails association confusion in controller and view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using **Devise** for user authentication in rails.
I have 2 models in my rails app:-

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
      :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

   has_one :userdetails
end
```

And

```
class Userdetail < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

In user_detail controller, I tried

```
def new
   @userdetail = Userdetail.new

end
```

I have created a user_id column in "userdetails" table that is associated with ID column in "users" table.

But when i update the value of userdetail the user_id field remains null.

I am a little bit confused what I have to write in "Controller", "view" and "Routes.rb" in order to set the user_id of the currently logged in user.
As I am new to RoR and stackoverflow please suggest me if i have missed to provide any info.

Comment: rename `userdetail` to `profile`, is one word, just a suggestion. And you will not confuse singular and plural, like you currently have: `has_one :something_in_plural`, that's weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way of instantiating a UserDetails record for the user is:

```
def new
   @userdetail = current_user.userdetails.build
end
```

You also need to authenticate the user, to make sure he's logged in, which also makes `current_user` object available to you. You need to include the following `before_action` in your `UserDetailsController`

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

In your `create` action you must follow the same principle:

```
def create
    @userdetail = current_user.userdetails.build(user_details_params)
    if @userdetail.save
     #...rest of the code
    end
end
```